# Idle mackerel tabby terminology question

Tags: cats, biology, genetics

It is said that "mackerel tabby" cats (tiger tabbies) always have an M on their foreheads, made of two stripes forming a chevron (^) on each side of the centerline.

[image: top view of Harry's head, showing the mackerel tabby M pattern]

My two, as shown by Harry here, also have an oval "rosette" at the top of the head, lighter fur with a few roughly symmetric fragments of stripe within it, bounded by mostly-solid stripes on either side. The pattern is different on each cat.

So I was just wondering whether this unique rosette/shield/blazon has been given a name by cat fanciers, or if it's not a common enough part of the pattern to have gotten that attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No special name, it is simply how his fur is colored and how it grows.

Hey, a cat looks the way the cat looks. We have had cats with markings that made then look almost as thought they were wearing glasses.

Naming attributes has always seemed a tad odd to me, but that's me.

Comment: Given the silence, that does seem to be the answer...   On the other hand, people do specifically point out the M as distinctive to this pattern, so ya never know.